# Does origen_testers V93K support test method libraries with different classes?

Tags: origen-sdk

We have custom test method libraries that support a couple different test method classes.  For example:

- test93k.common.Functional
- test93kcustomext.common.Functional

Would I need to create different test method libraries in our test interface using the `add_tml` method or can they both exist in the same test method library?  In the end, we need the correct class to show up in the generated flow as so:

```
testmethods

tm_jtag_regular:
  testmethod_class = "test93k.common.Functional";
tm_jtag_extension:
  testmethod_class = "test93kcustomext.common.Functional";
```

What controls the test that goes above?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a `class_name:` option to both the library and the individual tests, so you could try:

```rb
add_tml :my_tml,
  class_name: '',     # Try setting this to nothing

  functional: {
    class_name: 'test93k.common.Functional',
  },

  functional_ext: {
    class_name: 'test93kcustomext.common.Functional',       
  }
```

There's a chance that the final name might end up with a leading `.`, though it should be a simple patch to make it inhibit that if the TML class name is blank.

Defining them as two separate TMLs would definitely work too, and is probably how it should be handled:

```rb
add_tml :regular,
  class_name: 'test93k.common',

  functional: {
    class_name: 'Functional',   # May not even need this
  }

add_tml :ext,
  class_name: 'test93kcustomext.common',

  functional: {
    class_name: 'Functional',   # May not even need this
  }
```

See here for more - https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/v93k/#Custom_Test_Methods

Comment: changing it with the first method won't work as it will still append whatever the test method library ID is to the front of the class.  The second option looks like the only way to do it.

Comment: I guess there must be some logic in there that currently treats an empty string class name the same as no class name given and in that case it defaults to deriving the class name from the ID. Arguably it shouldn't do that and there should be a way to specify no class name.
However, the 2nd approach is certainly the intended way to handle something like this anyway.